# Python calling event by clicking on button in gooeypie

Tags: python

I have got two classes one to hold request object and second to generate UI. My problem is - When I press 'Add' button I get an error on calling an event.

```
import gooeypie as gp

class Request:

    def __init__(self,
                 request_number = ""):

        self.request_number = request_number

class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = gp.GooeyPieApp('Request')
        self.app.width = 300
        self.app.set_grid(10, 4)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        self.request_lbl = gp.Label(self.app, 'Number')
        self.request_inp = gp.Input(self.app)
        self.generate_btn = gp.Button(container=self.app, text='Add', event_function= self.add)

        self.app.add(self.request_lbl, 2, 1, align='right')
        self.app.add(self.request_inp, 2, 2, column_span=2, fill=True)
        self.app.add(self.generate_btn, 10,1, column_span=4, fill=True)
        self.app.run()

    def add(self, event):
        request = Request(request_number=self.request_inp.text)
        print('Request Added')

w = Window()
```

Comment: I haven't used gooeypie, but I'm not comfortable with `__init__` calling `initialize` which calls `app.run()` .  Since `app.run()` doesn't return, you've got a chain of calls resulting in `__init__` not returning.  Not sure if it's an issue, but it seems problematic.  You might want to add a run method to your window that you can call after your window is created, with `w.run()`.